# Compute multiple variables in R

Tags: r

I have a series of reaction times: trail1 to trail100, and a subsequent answer1 to answer100.

I want the new variables computed in R:
If trail1 is the value 1 to 15 then the correspondent answer1 should be the value of answer1.
If trial1 is 0 then the correspondent answer1 should be -1

```
ID <- c("1", "2", "3")
Trial1 <- c("3", "0", "8")
Trial2 <- c("5", "6", "15")
Trial3 <- c("14", "15", "10")
Answer1 <- c("489", "368", "-1")
Answer2 <- c("363", "967", "671")
Answer3 <- c("700", "1201", "890")

df <- data.frame(ID, Trial1, Trial2, Trial3, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3)
```

correct new variables (new_answer1 to 100) should be:

```
ID <- c("1", "2", "3")
Trial1 <- c("3", "0", "8")
Trial2 <- c("5", "6", "15")
Trial3 <- c("14", "15", "10")
New_Answer1 <- c("489", "-1", "-1")
New_Answer2 <- c("363", "967", "671")
New_Answer3 <- c("700", "1201", "890")

df1 <- data.frame(ID, Trial1, Trial2, Trial3, New_Answer1, New_Answer2, New_Answer3)
```

Thank you

Comment: why 671 changed to -1 in expected?  the corresponding Trial2 value is 15 and not 0

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, changed the corresponding NEW_answer2 value.

Comment: Is it possible to loop something like this?                                                                     
          df %>% 
  mutate(New_Answer1 = case_when(Trial1 >= 1 ~ Answer1
                                 ,Trial1 <= 1 ~ Trial1
                                 ,TRUE ~ Answer1)
     
                              )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, a simple expresion is needed:

```
New_Answer1 <- Answer1
New_Answer1[Trial1==0] <- -1
```

Out:

```
> New_Answer1
[1] "489" "-1"  "-1"
```

Comment: Is it possible to repeat this for every trial, with a loop for example?

Comment: Of course! Make sure that trial (and answer if needed) elements change in every iteration and apply the above expresion inside loop. Take into account that you might want to save the trials or answer values before a new iteration is started!